# How to use a service class in a react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am unsuccessfully trying to initialise and use a service class from a React hook.
The service class looks like:

```
export class ExampleService {
  constructor(private exampleParams: string[]) {}

  isPresent(exampleName: string): boolean {
    return this.exampleParams.includes(exampleName);
  }

  getAll(): string[] {
    return this.exampleParams;
  }

  setExamples(exampleParams: string[]): void {
    this.exampleParams = exampleParams;
  }
}
```

And then in the hook I am trying to use this class:

```
import { ExampleService } from '../somewhere/example-service';
import { useContext } from 'react';

import { ExampleContext } from '../contexts/example-context';

export const useExample = () => {
  const { currentExamples } = useContext(ExampleContext);
  const checkExamples = new ExampleService(currentExamples);

  return [checkExamples.isPresent];
};
```

However, I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'exampleParams' of undefined` when I try to test the code :/
(The error is on `isPresent` function above).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `currentExamples` after you are getting from `useContext(ExampleContext)`?

Comment: `currentExamples` I'd be getting from `useContext(ExampleContext)` is an array of strings `['example-1', 'example-2']`

Comment: How are you using your `useExample` hook? The functon you return within your array is going to be unbound, so calling it won't have `this` set to `checkExamples` unless you explicitly do so. You need something like `[checkExamples.isPresent.bind(checkExamples)]` or `[(...args) => checkExamples.isPresent(...args)]`

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can also use codesandbox where you can make your code runnable

Comment: `[checkExamples.isPresent.bind(checkExamples)]` did the work! Thank you so much @NickParsons ❤️